# Will pre-populating a php field using json work?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to populate a field with the email address of the person that logged in.  Since this app is used by various clients, I want to add the code as needed to the external javascript code.  I have been working with json, but now i wonder if this is the answer.

**In my php code I have this:**

```
<?php
$myemail = $this->session->userdata('USER_EMAIL');
//echo $myemail;
```

**next I have this:**

```
var $jsonEmail = trim(json_encode($myemail));
```

**Then in my js custom page I have this:**

```
var jsonObj = $jsonEmail;
document.getElementById("email-12").innerHTML=jsonObj.value;
```

It's not working, but since I am new to this, I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why use JSON if it's a single string?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing PHP and JavaScript which doesn't work. Your PHP should look like this:

```
$jsonEmail = trim(json_encode($myemail)); // Get rid of 'var'
```

Your JavaScript should look like this:

```
var jsonObj = <?php echo $jsonEmail; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, It will be dirty, but I think will work.

```
var jsonObj = <?php echo $jsonEmail ?>;
document.getElementById("email-12").innerHTML=jsonObj.value;
```

You can't mix serverside PHP with localside Javascript. PHP write text to SDIO, and the browser interpret it like things, like JS code, or HTML.

Comment: I am getting unexpected token illegal, when I try these and the issue is I want to place the json/javascript into a separate js page, that is specific to the client, not in the main body of code.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to echo your `$jsonEmail` variable to your JavaScript, eg:

```
var jsonObj = <?php echo $jsonEmail; ?>
document.getElementById("email-12").innerHTML=jsonObj.value;
```